# Saving the entity as a list in the associated database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table named Issue and I have a list type confirm table in this table. How can I access and change the fields in this list?

```
var vIssues = await _context.Issues
    .Include(x => x.User)
    .Include(x => x.IssueConfirms)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.DepartmentId == departmentId && x.UserId.ToString() == vUserId);

vIssues.IssueConfirms.Select(x => new IssueConfirm
    {
        Status = Enums.Confirm.ConfirmStatus.MailGonderildiBeklemede
    })
    .ToList();
    
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but it is not saving my database.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Issueconfirms database but ı am using await _context.savechanges

Comment: You have not changed anything, but created new objects with some new values. EF will not handle this.

Comment: How can I savechanges the changes in the IssueConfirms table where I have selected the field?

Comment: Iterate over `vIssues.IssueConfirms` by `foreach` and just update  needed property.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` will return a new IEnumerable. You are not modifying data.
`Foreach` will iterate over the IEnumerable and enables modification.

For example:

```
vIssues.IssueConfirms.Foreach(x => x.Status = Enums.Confirm.ConfirmStatus.MailGonderildiBeklemede).ToList();
```

Comment: But its not working foreach.Because my issueconfirms list is ICollection type.Fixed it when ı made it is list type